# Mongoose update gets no errors, but does not update

Tags: express, mongoose

Cant figure out what I'm missing, and I havent had this issue before on any of my other updates. I expanded a collection and want to be able to update certain fields depending on where in the app the user is interacting. I've had no issue working with subdocs using separate calls, but with this particular nested field I'm getting no errors, and getting the correct document returned without the update. (I have another nested field that is updating fine - "personalInfo" while the "medical" field is the one giving me trouble)

The model looks like this:

```
const clientSchema = new Schema({
    fullName: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    enrollment: {
        enrolled: Boolean,
        enrollDates: [
            {
                begin: Date,
                end: Date
            }
        ]
    },
    personalInfo: {
        dateOfBirth: Date,
        phone: String,
        email: String,
        address: {
            addressLineOne: String,
            addressLineTwo: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            zip: String
        },
        regionalCenter: String,
        serviceCoordinator: String,
        serviceCoordinatorPhone: String,
        rcId: String,
        emergencyContact: String,
        livingSituation: String,
        ihss: {
            provider: String,
            hours: Number,
            services: String
        }

    },
    medical: {
        primaryIns: String,
        primaryInsId: String,
        secondaryIns: String,
        secondaryInsId: String,
        hasMediCal: Boolean,
        mediCalId: String,
        mediCalEnroll: Date,
        hasMedicare: Boolean,
        medicareId: String,
        medicareEnroll: Date,
        logs: {type: [logSchema], default: []},
    },
    contracts: {type: [contractSchema], default: []},
    visits: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Visit' }],
    users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    servicePlans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ServicePlan'}],
    currentPlan: String,
    income: {type: [incomeSchema], default: []},
    contacts: {type: [contactSchema], default: []}

}
```

The route:

```
router.route("/clients/:clientId").patch(updateClient)
```

And the controller... since I want to keep the controller as restful as possible, but conditionally set the fields depending on the api call, I conditionally set the different aspects and then pass in the body an additional field to tell the controller which aspect to update (so the personalInfo section has a field "personalInfo": "personalInfo" and the medicalInfo field has its own. The personalInfo object updates fine (I commented out the initial line since it was stated in another post that these calls work better doing a findOneAndUpdate- but that hasnt yielded any progress, and the personalInfo update worked without issue).

```
exports.updateClient = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //const client = await Client.findOne({ _id: req.params.clientId })

        if (req.body.firstName) {
            client.firstName = req.body.firstName
        }

        if (req.body.lastName) {
            client.lastName = req.body.lastName
        }

        if (req.body.personalInfo === 'personalInfo') {
            
            client.updateOne({$set: {personalInfo: req.body}}, {new: true}, function(err, updatedDoc){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error updating personal info: ", err)
                }
            })
        }

        if (req.body.enrollment === 'enrollment') {
            client.updateOne({$set: {enrollment: req.body}}, {new: true}, function(err, updatedDoc){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error updating personal info: ", err)
                }
            })
        }

        if(req.body.medicalInfo === 'medicalInfo'){
            console.log("medInfo: ", req.body)
            let clientId = req.params.clientId

            // const client = await Client.findById(clientId)
            // console.log("Client ", client)
            // client.medical.set(req.body)
            Client.findById(clientId)
            .then((client) => {
                client.medical.set(req.body
                    // hasMediCal: req.body.hasMediCal,
                    // hasMedicare: req.body.hasMedicare,
                    // mediCalId: req.body.mediCalId,
                    // medicareId: req.body.medicareId,
                    // mediCalEnroll: req.body.mediCalEnroll,
                    // medicareEnroll: req.body.medicareEnroll,
                    // primaryIns: req.body.primaryIns,
                    // primaryInsId: req.body.primaryInsId,
                    // secondaryIns: req.body.secondaryIns,
                    // secondaryInsId: req.body.secondaryInsId
                );
                client.save();
                res.send(client)
         })
            
            // Client.findOneAndUpdate(
            //     { _id: req.params.clientId},
            //     {$set: {medical: req.body}}, 
            //     {new: true}, 
            //     function(err, updatedDoc){
            //     if(err){
            //         console.log("error updating personal info: ", err)
            //     }
            // })
            // client.markModified('medical');
        }


        
        // await client.save()
        // res.send(client)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404)
        res.send({ error: "Client not updated: ", error})
    }
}
```

Finally, the body being sent:

```
{
    "hasMediCal": false,
    "hasMedicare": false,
    "mediCalEnroll": "2005-04-22T08:00:00",
    "mediCalId": "91234567A",
    "medicalInfo": "medicalInfo",
    "medicareEnroll": "2005-04-03T08:00:00",
    "medicareId": "9FHS-ASU-95F8",
    "primaryIns": "Molina",
    "primaryInsId": "91234567A",
    "secondaryIns": "SilverScript - Rx",
    "secondaryInsId": "08dfA8d8"
}
```

Whether I've tried findOneAndUpdate, or findOne and then setting the field on the result, or setting each subfield in the object specifically, I keep getting the correct document returned, just not updated, and with no errors. I thought possibly it was because I was attempting to set the update within the conditionals, so I created a separate update controller but that got the same results as well. Really lost as how else to pursue this.

Please let me know if you see anything missing or where I'm going wrong. Much appreciated.

Comment: `personalInfo` schema is different and `body` being sent has schema of medical, then how it will get updated?

Comment: I'm trying to get the update for the medical section working. personalInfo works fine with the call as written in the controller. Depending on if the body has a 'personalInfo' field or a 'medicalInfo' field, the controller should follow the different functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after running around on this for hours, I came to a working solution, which essentially is no different, other than setting the query as a variable rather than writing it out. If anyone has any guess as to why this works when the multiple other methods didnt, I'd be grateful for your thoughts.

```
if(req.body.medicalInfo === 'medicalInfo'){
            console.log("medInfo: ", req.body)
            let clientId = req.params.clientId
            let query = {_id: clientId};
            
            Client.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$set: {medical: req.body}}, {new: true, upsert: true}, function(err, doc){
                if(err) return res.status(500).send( {error:err});
                return res.send(doc)
            })

        }
```